# How to validate against runtime JSON object reference?

Tags: json, jsonschema

For a sample JSON data which looks like this -

```
{
    "children":{
        "Alice":{...},
        "Jamie":{...},
        "Bob":{...}
        // Any new child with a given unique name will be added to this object
    },
    childrenOrder:["Alice", "Bob", "Jamie"]
}
```

In the corresponding JSON Schema, I am trying to limit the valid values in "childrenOrder" array to be from the run time children keys.
I didn't see any means of referring to runtime dynamic values in the official JSON Schema documentation (http://json-schema.org/documentation.html).

Is this even possible at the moment?
For the sake of brevity I omitted JSON Schema code. I can add it if folks think it is needed to address the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible using the current JSON Schema specification.  However, there is a proposal for the next version of JSON Schema that could change that.

https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/%24data-(v5-proposal)

Comment: Thanks for confirming on this and also for pointing me to the possible solution (if/when it happens). Marking this as answered.