# JSON schema validate input based on list at runtime

Tags: jsonschema

I'd like to know if I can define a schema to perform validation based on list of values at runtime. Example:

```
people:
- joe
- fred
- anna

bestfriend: ike
```

I'd like to define a schema where the value of `bestfriend`  is limited to the values of `people` . The schema defines `people` as array of string.

It looks a little like [How to validate against runtime JSON object reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262478/how-to-validate-against-runtime-json-object-reference) where the answer is outdated.

Comment: This is still correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, but you could generate a new schema at runtime containing those values and then evaluate against that.