# Jsonschema validate

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I am working on a Json schema validation and below is the code. I need to have a schema check for element 'pii'.

The values should only be columns defined in columns (field1,field2 or field3) with a combination of none to all column names.
The columns names and number of columns are dynamic and differs for every json. Current json example below has 3 columnnames, next may have more.

1. How do I add the schema check for pii?
2. Is there a better way to validate that the column_names(field1, field2, field3), column_description or column_datatype has a value in it?
3. Can I restrict column data type to a set of data types values ['integer','string','object']

Thanks for your time!

```
import json
import jsonschema

sample_data= {
    "title": "aaaa.bbbb.cccc",
    "description": "customer accounts sample",
    "owner_email": "abc.def@xyz.com",
    "output_type": "parquet",
    "version": "V1.0",
    "columns":
    {   "field1":
        {   "column_description": "Description for field1",
            "column_datatype": "string"
        },
        "field2":
        {   "column_description": "Description for field2",
            "column_datatype": "string"
        },
        "field3":
        {   "column_description": "Description for field3",
            "column_datatype": "string"
        }
    },
    "pii":["field1","field2"]
}

FileSchema = {
    "definitions":
    {
        "columnschema":
        {
            "properties":
            {
                "column_description": { "type" : "string" },
                "column_datatype": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["column_description", "column_datatype"]
        }
    },

    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "title", "description", "owner_email", "output_type", "version","columns" ],
    "properties": 
    {   "title": {"type":"string"},
        "description": {"type":"string"},
        "owner_email": {"type":"string"},
        "output_type": {"type":"string"},
        "version": {"type":"string"},
        "columns":
        {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "[A-Za-z0-9]" :{ "$ref": "#/definitions/columnschema" }
                                }
        }
    }
}

jsonschema.validate(instance=sample_data, schema=FileSchema)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON schema validate input based on list at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65378991/json-schema-validate-input-based-on-list-at-runtime)

Comment: It's not possible to use instance data in your schema. I've marked this as a duplicate question, although I understand they may seem unrelated.